# Trying to find 3 columns from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Pins (
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    boardID int NOT NULL,
    ));

CREATE TABLE Boarders (
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    boardID int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (categoryName) REFERENCES Category (name));


CREATE TABLE User (
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (email));
```

I am wanting to make the  query search results this: for each Pin, show the description

This obviously is not working, but any suggestions on how to get the above to display?

Comment: Google **examples of inner join in MySQL**

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: What's obviously not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.description ,c.title, u.name from PushPin p,CorkBoard c, User u
    where c.email=u.email and c.email =p.email  and c.boardID = p.boardID 
      order by p.description
```

Comment: Stop using comma based implicit joins. Use explicit `Join` based syntax

Comment: where you  have  found the column description  ?.. i don't see this column in OP schema

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will require you to join the three tables.

Something like the below code should work. 
Just defining the Foreign key relations does not mean you would not need to join while querying.

```
SELECT PP.description, CB.title, U.name
FROM PushPin PP JOIN CorkBoard CB ON PP.boardID = CB.boardID
   JOIN USSER U ON PP.email = U.email
WHERE description like '$search'
ORDER BY description;
```

Comment: where you  have  found the column description  ?.. i don't see this column in OP schema

Comment: The OP has edited his/her question since the answer.